# Excel VBA error 1004 on Interior.ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to debug an excel report that someone else wrote.  When the user clicks on a macro button it gives this error

[image].
When I click on debug button it goes to this function.  I tried adding unprotect but don't know the password not sure if that would have worked.

```
Sub ClearFormatting()
    'Sheets("InvoiceData").Unprotect
    
    Sheets("InvoiceData").Range("A2:Z9999").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    'Sheets("InvoiceData").Protect
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a sheet in your workbook with the name: InvoiceData

Comment: @Sorceri Yes that is the only sheet in the workbook

Comment: ok, then is that sheet protected?  IF so, then you need to unprotect it in order to make changes to the sheet.  There is nothing wrong with the code you presented.

Comment: Dont think that is the issue there is a almost identical sheet with a one word difference in the macro that is working  I just copy pasted that and changed the word.  Maybe it's the data the user is pasting in.

Answer (score 0):

Th issue is the protected sheet.  I used your code on an unprotected sheet, and it works fine (keep in mind color index 0 is white). When running on a protected sheet, I get the same error as you.

If you do not know the password, you cannot use .Unprotect.  However, you can copy all the data in that sheet to a new sheet, delete the InvoiceData sheet and then rename the new sheet InvoiceData.  Remember to copy any macros out of the sheet before you delete it.  Always backup before doing something like this.